# How to calculate a fiscal day of year in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula

I'm working with Excel. I have a calendar date, fiscal year, fiscal month, fiscal quarter. I need to calculate the day of fiscal year.

Fiscal year starts on April 1st and ends on March 31st.

How can I calculate the day of fiscal year where: 1 Apr = 1,  2 Apr = 2 , .... 31 March = 365.

Is there any formula for this?

Comment: What have you tried and what problems have you run into.  It should be a simple subtraction problem.

Comment: Have a look at [Date and time functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb#__toc309306709). *hint:* use `=EDATE(<DATE>, 4)` to adjust the differential.

Comment: [Here](http://a4accounting.com.au/excel-and-days-within-the-financial-year/) is another resource.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are in ColumnA and you have a cell in the same workbook containing the previous year end, named `LastFYend` and of workbook scope, then perhaps:

```
=TEXT(A1-LastFYend,"0")
```